# Should i implement all the interfaces in one class or make one class for each one?

Tags: java, interface

I have an assignment to build a self evaluation test grader. The teacher gave us test interfaces:

[image: Test interface UML diagram]

and question interfaces:

[image: Question interface UML diagram]

to implement, and I don't know whether I'm supposed to implement them all in one class like this:

```
public class CQuestion implements IQuestion, IQuestionMultipleChoice,
        IQuestionNumeric, IQuestionYesNo,IQuestionMetadata {}

public class CTest implements ITest,ITestStatistics {}
```

or whether I should do one class for each question type.

I tried the first approach but I get errors because there are methods with the same name.

I want try the second approach, but I don't know how to do it. I know I have to create a question object inside the test class, but I don't know whether I if have to create one object for each question type.

Comment: The use case description is important. What does it say? How does it specify this should be done? What's the purpose of this program in general?

Comment: "*I tried the first approach but i get errors because there are methods with the same name.*" -- if the interfaces have conflicting requirements for methods -- and it looks like they do -- then that pretty much answers that part of the question.  But I don't think you need any direct implementation of `IQuestion`.

Comment: @lealceldeiro it should look like this in the final result https://imgur.com/a/iTOTVT5

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the test interfaces, I don't see why you couldn't (at first glance), and I think you should implement both interfaces.

In the case of the question interfaces, as you've found out, there are incompatibilities in the method signatures. Since `IQuestionMultipleChoice`, `IQuestionNumeric` and `IQuestionYesNo` all extend `IQuestion`, you only need to implement one of the first three. As @john-bollinger pointed out in the comments, there is no need to implement `IQuestion` if you implement one of the three dub-interfaces.

I think you should also implement `IQuestionMetaData`, with something like that

```
public class CQuestionYesNo implements IQuestionYesNo, IQuestionMetaData {
... // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know whether I'm supposed to implement them all in one class [...] or whether I should do one class for each question type.
>
> I tried the first approach but i get errors because there are methods with the same name

... and arguments, but different return types.  Let's apply some simple logic here, then: if two interfaces have conflicting requirements, then they cannot both be implemented by the same class.  Thus, it appears that there must be separate concrete classes implementing `IQuestionMultipleChoice`, `IQuestionNumeric`, and `IQuestionYesNo`.  Because all those interfaces extend `IQuestion`, each of those implementations will also necessarily implement `IQuestion`, so there seems no inherent need for a separate implementation of that.  Nevertheless, it would be fairly natural to have a base class for the others that implements `IQuestion` directly.

Inasmuch as `IQuestion` has methods to get and set metadata, it does not look like it would be useful for any of the aforementioned classes to implement `IQuestionMetaData`.  There should surely be a separate class for that.

Similarly, `ITest` has methods to add and remove `IQuestion`s and to provide `ITestStatistics`, so it does not appear that a typical implementation of the former would also implement either of the latter.  It appears, then, that there should also be separate implementations of `ITest` and `ITestStatistics`.

> I want try the second approach, but I don't know how to do it. I know
>   I have to create a question object inside the test class, but I don't
>   know whether I if have to create one object for each question type.

Why would an `ITest` implementation need to create question objects?  It has methods with which a separate object can add and remove questions.  I see no reason to think that a test is expected to be able to create its own questions.

---

#### Important note:

You said that your job is to implement a *grader*, but **none of the above** appear to be part of the implementation of a grader.  Those interfaces seem instead to describe the subject on which your grader will operate.  That does not necessarily  mean that you're not expected to implement those interfaces, but you should make sure of that before you put in the work.  From my perspective, it is entirely possible that you're expected to rely on the interfaces in your grader implementation, but not to provide your own implementations of them.

Comment: Two questions:

1- In the ITest implementation what´s inside the addQuestion method?
2- I didn´t get from your explanation if i should implement and "IQuestion" Class. I dont´t think its necessary since the methods from that interface are automatically inside the other 3 classes.

PS: Maybe Grader isn´t the corret term. Basically we are given a set of questions in a json file, and from that ,the program needs to be able to identify what type of question it is and a load the specific test window for that question type. The end result should be like this https://imgur.com/a/iTOTVT5.

Comment: @BrunoCunha, 1. I don't know what *your instructor's* intent is, but my expectation from reading the method signature is that that method stores the provided `Question` in an internal data structure of some kind -- a `List` perhaps.

Comment: 2. I discuss this in the latter part of the my first paragraph.  There seems no inherent need to provide a direct implementation of `IQuestion`, but you might nevertheless find it *useful* to provide one to use as a superclass for the implementations of the three other question interfaces.